# Why I can't get jQuery work online?

Tags: jquery, offline

I'm using jQuery for the first time and maybe there's something I haven't notice.
This page http://iziratig.zymichost.com/index.html works all the way fine offline but jQuery's on fitting embedded MySpace videos and on slideshow in bottom right corner don't when online.

p.s. I've spent few evenings with google seeking for solution :D

Comment: jQuery seems to be loaded just fine. What's the question, specifically? What are we supposed to see?

Comment: Embedded video should fit in left side div by width in any screen size (which it does offline) and there's comic strip slide show in right bottom corner (visible in offline too).

Comment: I've tried with two different servers so I suppose it's about my code or something.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL
>   http://iziratig.zymichost.com/index.html from frame with URL
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/30hMJMvPxGo. Domains, protocols and ports
>   must match.

Answer (score 0):

You should load your jQuery library and other js within `<head>`, so put following two line within your `<head>`.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

and also add `type="text/javascript"` to the `<script>` tag where you write you Javascript/jQUery code that is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
     // code
  });

</script>
```

Comment: No difference. Comic strip slideshow and iframe size still not work :(